# How do I make a line graph with markers?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

So I am trying to use openpyxl library to make a line with markers. Dataset like:

```
df = [['System1 Account Unlock','week 1',1],
['System2 Password Reset','week 1',2],
['Website','week 1',3],
['System2 (problem)','week 2',1],
['System1 Password Reset','week 2',2],
['Website','week 2',1],
['System2 Password Reset','week 3',2],
['Website','week 3',5],
['System2 (problem)','week 3',1],
['System1 Password Reset','week 4',2],
['System1 Account Unlock','week 4',2],
['Website','week 4',2],
['System2 (problem)','week 4',4],
['System2 Password Reset','week 4',4],
['Website','week 5',1],
['System1 Password Reset','week 5',1],
['System1 Account Unlock','week 5',2]]
```

AND THEN I PASTED THESE VALUES ONTO A WORKSHEET NAMED, 'ws'.

Then I used:

```
xvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=17)
yvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=3, min_row=1, max_col=3, max_row=17)
legend_values = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=17)
```

To get the columns so it looks like this:

[image: IMAGE OF GRAPH]

[image: EXCEL REFERENCE]

What I tried:
-using Series class but and adding x,y and legend but that resulted in 1 line instead of multiple lines
-using linechart but resulted in 1 line
-removing legend and y and just throwing all the data at a go... result was 2 lines named Series 1 and Series 2 instead of in the pic

I need help making the graph with df[0] or category being the legend markers, df[1] or weeks being the x-axis and df[2] or number of incidents being the y-axis

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I made the data look like this in the sheet:

```
       col1   col2  col3  col4 
week 1  5      8     0     15
week 2  6      7     1     6
week 3  1      7     4     2
week 4  4      0     0     0
week 5  0      0     0     0
```

Then I used a scatter chart next instead of line chart

changes the x_axis.majorUnit to 1

```
xvalues = Reference(ws, min_col-1,min_row=1,max_row=17)
for i in range(1, 17):
   values = Reference(ws, min_col-1,min_row=1,max_row=17)
   series = Series(values, xvalues)
   chart.series.append(series)
```

and that solved my problem of making a line with markers

> not perfect but doable